# Finding total number of subsequences in an array with consecutive difference = k

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subsequence

In the given array, I am trying to find the total number of  subsequences such that:

- the difference between the consecutive terms is not greater than 3
- the first element of the subsequence is the first element of the array
- the last element of the subsequence is the last element of the array

For example, in an array: `[10,13,7,8,14,200, 876, 11]`, it has 5 subsequences which follow the above condition.

I am trying a bottom-up approach to this. I tried the following, but it does not give all the subsequences and outputs 4 instead of 5.

How can I approach this? I have an intuition that the approach could be similar to Longest Increasing Subsequence, but not sure how.

Comment: Can you please provide the the 4 sequences your code is giving?

Comment: @VFX updated .. it prints everything except `[10,13,11]`

Comment: You are only interested in the number of sequences that fulfill your conditions right? you don't need to print the actual sequences

Comment: @VFX No........

Comment: @VFX Do you also feel this is a variation of LIS (Longest Increasing Subsequence) problem?

Comment: Counting the number of sequences can be done O(n^2) in a similar way to LIS, but printing the sequences can be done in O(2^n), where n is the length of the array A

Comment: Actually in the problem statement it is mentioned that the number of sequences is the required result. so to be sure about it can you please tell me what is the maximum length of the array A?

Comment: @VFX Alright, I am trying to get the count.

Comment: Ok thanks noted, I am writing the code

Comment: @Amanda is the difference between consecutive terms fixed (like 3 in your example) or is it variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let f(i) be the number of subsequences that fulfill the following conditions:

- Start by A[0]
- End by A[i]
- The difference between the consecutive terms is not greater than 3

Then the answer to your problem will be f(A.length()-1).

Here is the code in C++ in a bottom-up approach:

```
int A[] = {10,13,7,8,14,11};
int f[6];
int n = 6;
    
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) f[i] = 0;
f[0]=1;
for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
  for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
     if (abss(A[i] - A[j]) <= 3)
         f[i] += f[j];
  }
}
cout<<f[n-1]<<endl;//printing the result
```

Here is the code written in C++ in top-down approach:

```
int A[] = {10,13,7,8,14,11};
int n = 6;

int memo[6];//initialized with -1s;

int count(int currIndex){
  if (currIndex == n-1) return 1;
  if (memo[currIndex] != -1) return memo[currIndex];
  
  int res = 0;
  for (int i=currIndex+1 ; i<n ; i++){
      if (abss(A[currIndex] - A[i]) <= 3){
            res += count(i);
      }
  }
    
  memo[currIndex] = res;
  return res;
}
```

And the result will be by calling count at first index like this:

```
count(0);
```

Comment: [Here is a translation to JavaScript](https://jsbin.com/yugununosi/1/edit?js,console). I don't actually understand the problem enough, so I'm not sure if the output is correct. So, I hope I've not made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: ok I will check your code, my code is printing 5 correctly, you can run it here
https://onlinegdb.com/HyQqH4DX_w

Comment: Ah, OK - then this produces the same output. There was a small issue - I had it printing the whole array by accident. [Here is the corrected code](https://jsbin.com/dadunojuba/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: if you don't understand the logic I can explain with more details, so let me know please

Comment: I have understood the code but did not why you did this. What does each index in `f` represent?

Comment: Could you point out a recursive solution to make it more clearer?

Comment: ok I will write the top-down approach using recursion

Comment: I provided the recursive solution in my answer, please let me know if you don't understand it. and here is the full code https://onlinegdb.com/i9Sj3St-q

Comment: I am unable to reason, as to why this is working. Also why do we start with `f[0]=1;` in dynamic?

Comment: Ok I will try to come up with a good explanation that clarifies the idea

Comment: ````f[0]=1;```` means the number of sequences that start by A[0] and end by A[0] and fulfull the <= 3 condition is 1 sequence. this is a trivial case

Comment: Do you understand the definition of function f(i)?

Comment: ok then I will try to provide a full explanation, and in the mean while you can simulate the code on paper for a small test case, it will help you a lot to understand

Comment: I have understood it now. Took me a while, but this is so clever.

Comment: How did you work out the solution so quickly?

Comment: Please give me some tips. I want to be like this too. Where can I find problems such as these?

Comment: @VFX is that ```O(N^2)```?

Comment: Ok sure I can provide you with some tips, but maybe we can communicate using Facebook, Telegram or some other media so we don't violate Stackeoverflow rules?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur yes it is considered O(n^2) and to be more accurate it is n(n+1)/2 because it is the sum of the sequence 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n

Comment: @VFX that's the same as O(N^2)

Comment: What is the base case here? Is it `f[0]=1`?

Comment: Yes ````f[0]=1```` is the base case

Comment: And what about f[i] = 0 initialization? I thought that was the base case.

Comment: ````f[i] = 0 initialization```` is a normal zero initialization and not a base case, like when you initialize your counters with zero, because ````f[i] += f[j]```` is like a counter and we need to start from zero. On the other hand, a base case is a value that is required to compute the bigger cases

Answer (score 1):

@VFX has already proposed a `O(N^2)` solution, but in most cases an optimised algorithm would be preferred. So here's a `O(K*N)` solution.
Let's say your first element in the subsequence is `x`. The next element has to be in the range `[x-k, x+k]`. If you know the number of valid sequences for all values in that range, you can find the answer for the current element in `O(K)` as well.
More formally, the algorithm would be:

```
arr = []              // your list
counter = {}          // a dictionary or hashmap to keep count of sequences
counter[arr[-1]] = 1
for i in range (len(arr)-2 to 0):
    curr_element = a[i]
    sequences = 0
    for x in range (curr_element-k to curr_element+k):
        sequences += counter[x]
    counter[curr_element] += sequences

final_answer = counter[arr[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed @Abhinav's answer to optimize the solution to `O(K*N)` instead of `O(N^2)` which will work fine for a small `K`.
But if an optimal solution is required I would suggest an `O(N*log2(N))` solution, where finding the sum in the range `[x-k,x+k]` can
be done in log2(N) using [Segment Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/) or [Binary Indexed Tree(Fenwick Tree)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-indexed-tree-or-fenwick-tree-2/) where Range Sum Query(RSQ) is a standard operation that these 2 data structures provide.

In case the values inside the initial array are big(like long or double), a data compression can be done with the help of a Map.
In this approach you don't need to worry about `K` even if it was too big.